# How can I only enable physics within a specific area?

Tags: physics

All the force field types in Blender seem to only suggest they work through the entirety of the scene. What I'd like to do is restrict what is affected by the physics.

If I had e.g. a turbulence object within a large cube, and I used keyframe animation to move the cube/turbulence around the scene, the objects that are completely within the cube on a given frame are affected by the turbulence. Once the cube moves away and an object leaves its bounds, the object should no longer be affected by the turbulence.

I'm aware I can enable and disable physics on individual objects with keyframing, but attempting to do this with hundreds of objects in a way that looks as natural as the system I'm describing above seems disproportionately difficult.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. Maybe some add-on may be capable of such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment; if that is the case, could you promote it to an answer?